# Thrift generated Java code generates loads of warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, thrift

Our project uses several thrift-generated classes. The java code generated by these classes is generating several hundred warnings, most of them unused imports and not declaring a long serialVersionUID (from Comparable).

The rest of the codebase is... also generating warnings, to put it politely, and I don't want to just disable warnings of the type the thrift code is generating. Is there anything I can do with thrift to get it to generate better code? Is there a way to include warning suppression decoration in the generated code?

We're using thrift 0.9.1.

Comment: Since you tagged your question 'eclipse', I suppose that you are in fact using Eclipse.  You then have the option to apply automatic code cleanups via Eclipse, which in particular can remove unused imports and even generate static `serialVersionUID` fields.  I understand that it's suboptimal to post-process generated files, but I am doubtful that you can make a given version of Thrift generate cleaner code than it already does, or insert warning-suppression annotations.

Comment: You could put the generated code in its own jar module; something I'd do with or without these problems to be honest as generated code is a necessary evil that deserves to sit at its own special table. And then only disable the warnings in that Eclipse project.

Comment: I'm aware of Eclipse's code cleanup, but for several process-related reasons post-processing the code isn't really an option.

I'll look into segregating the code into it's own jar. That is a larger change than I'd like to make, but it does make sense. We're also using Maven - is this something Maven could help with?

Comment: Have you tried to delete "build" folder in your project folder?

Comment: Have you tried the current Thrift trunk? If not, please do. If the problem persists, throw a posting into the Thrift mailing list.

Comment: Happen to have a link or instructions? The Apache site lists 0.9.1 as the latest release. I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Turns out the thrift build commands rely on tools with versions higher than what I have in available Ubuntu 12 LTS. I'm going to upgrade and see if that works.

Comment: I am able to build thrift from git in Ubuntu 14 and used it to regenerate my thrift classes. It cleared up ~50 of 600 warnings and is still generating loads of unused imports (mostly collections from java.util and a lot of ByteBuffers)

Comment: @CPS: 0.9.1 is current release, that's true. You will need to build from development trunk from the source repo. [There are also some instructions regarding Ubuntu](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/debian) how to do that. The 0.9.2 release is planned to be available near time (can't give an exact date). If the problem persists, I'd like to ask you to put together a good test case and [file a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT).

Comment: JensG I did exactly that without much improvement. I'll see if I can cobble together an example and file a ticket.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2794

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the standard Thrift Java implementation is [Facebook Swift](https://github.com/facebook/swift).

You can use the the Swift Generator tool included with that software to generate annotated Java classes from your IDL which are much cleaner, and I'm pretty sure they have an option for modifying the templates as well.

If you don't want to use their included "Nifty" server, and integrate instead with the standard Thrift transports, you can use the `NiftyProcessorAdapters` utility class to create a TProcessor:

```
ThriftCodecManager codecManager = new ThriftCodecManager(
    new CompilerThriftCodecFactory(false)
);
List<ThriftEventHandler> eventList = Collections.emptyList();
ThriftServiceProcessor proc = new ThriftServiceProcessor(codecManager, eventList, svc);
this.multiplex.registerProcessor(name, NiftyProcessorAdapters.processorToTProcessor(proc));
```

The code that Swift generates is basically just POJOs, and should not be nearly as many warnings.  That said the Swift runtime pulls in a bunch of dependencies and may not be suitable for all applications.

Comment: Offering an alternative is not an actual answer to this question. I'd add that as a comment rather than the first thing you put (or dare I say: advertise) in your answer.

Comment: @Gimby I'm providing an answer the question, you're arguing semantics, and you're not even correct.  Take a look in the mirror, I'm done with you