# Error while compiling thrift generated classes with Java 1.5

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, compilation, thrift

```
`Platform`: Windows 7, MinGW, MSYS, Java 1.5
```

I have thrift 0.9.1 compiler (prebuilt for windows) and source. I use Ant to build java library.
I create one thrift idl and compile it with the compiler. No problem in generating code files.
I add these files in my project, and that add slf4j (downloaded from their site) and libthrift.
Most of the errors that I have previously (imports etc) are gone except for errors related to overriding methods.
So basically it complains like:

> The method clear() of type Server must override a superclass method

and similarly for `compareTo`, `write`, `read` etc. In short it complains about all methods that are overridden. This is all thrift compiler generated code and I haven't changed anything.

Is there any incompatibility? I cannot really find any mention of that. I have tried removing and then adding the libraries, I have also tried cleaning, refreshing, validating the project but the errors are still there.

I have also tried to compile the code (thrift code) but MinGW is also a huge headache. It cannot find `configure` even though I have installed it. And if I run the `msys` console, it is able to `configure` but cannot `make` complaining about `inttypes.h` not present (which is not in msys include directory but is present in MinGW include directory.).

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631900/thrift-generated-java-code-generates-loads-of-warnings or is that sth else?

Comment: BTW, on Windows don't use MinGW. There is a Visual Studio project in the compiler folder. You basically need only the flex/bison support, there is an install package for Windows somewehere on the web which will do. IIRC that's all. Works like a charm. From my knowledge the MinGW build does not work on Windows anymore, because of a bunch of MinGW-related bugs. Since the VS project works so good, there is no real need for that PITA anymore.

Comment: thats a secondary issue, I can get binary from their website too. But the main problem is that the generated code does not compile

Comment: "*But the main problem is that the generated code does not compile*" - Hard to believe, honestly. Can you prepare a test case?

Comment: I just added the important information you "forgot" to mention.

Comment: Yes, that should have helped, but as I didn't came across this issue before it didn't came to my mind to add. I will remember now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Java 5?  With Java 5 `@Override` doesn't search for methods on interfaces, only on superclasses.

If you are using a Java 5 compiler trying using a more recent javac (preferably 7 or 8) and see of that works.

**EDIT:**

Not sure if this is in your version of Thrift, but in mine it looks like there is a flag called `java5` that you an specify when generating code to specify that you want the generated code to be Java 5 compliant

```
java (Java):
    beans:           Members will be private, and setter methods will return void.
    private-members: Members will be private, but setter methods will return 'this' like usual.
    nocamel:         Do not use CamelCase field accessors with beans.
    fullcamel:       Convert underscored_accessor_or_service_names to camelCase.
    android:         Generated structures are Parcelable.
    android_legacy:  Do not use java.io.IOException(throwable) (available for Android 2.3 and above).
    java5:           Generate Java 1.5 compliant code (includes android_legacy flag).
    reuse-objects:   Data objects will not be allocated, but existing instances will be used (read and write).
    sorted_containers:
                     Use TreeSet/TreeMap instead of HashSet/HashMap as a implementation of set/map.
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew that.

Comment: Any way that I can make it run in 1.5 (just remove annotations)

Comment: Edited my answer to mention the java5 flag, hope that helps